# apt held packages, can't install package

Tags: 12.10, apt, mono

On Ubuntu 12.10 when trying

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

to install mono, I get:

```
enter codReading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-complete : Depends: mono-devel (= 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libmono-cil-dev (= 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried removing mono-devel and libmono-cil-dev but they are not installed.

I've tried

```
sudo apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

but it does not help.

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

does not give any results, so it seems that no packages are *actually* held.

I've also tried

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

and

```
apt-get install -f
```

neither of which helped either.

Strangely though, I *do* have mono installed in /usr/bin/mono.
The way that I got into this mess was that I tried to get the latest versions by following the directions here: http://www.meebey.net/posts/mono_3.0_preview_debian_ubuntu_packages/.
apt-get was complaining about held packages at which point I did

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I don't know if that was the cause of my current problems. Anyway, after it continued to complain about packages being held, I removed that experimental mono deb source from my sources and removed mono-complete, and ran apt-get clean, update, and upgrade, to get back the blank slate. At that point, I tried to install mono-complete from a blank slate, and arrived to my current situation.

EDIT:

```
$ apt-cache policy mono-devel libmono-cil-dev
mono-devel:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2.10.8.1-5ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libmono-cil-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2.10.8.1-5ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main i386 Packages
```

@meebey of the linked experimental page recommends apt-get remove cli-common for a full mono removal which outputs this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-xsp4 : Depends: mono-xsp4-base (= 2.10-2.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

**RESOLVED**
I resolved this issue by adding the experimental ppa back and removed mono-complete and cli-common. Then I removed the experimental ppa again which got me back to a blank slate. For that reason I don't consider this a duplicate issue, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `apt-cache policy mono-devel libmono-cil-dev`? Edit your question and add the details.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get check`?

Comment: apt-get check does not output anything except that it ran